Camera rotation on X axis with React Three Fiber
I just want to set my camera X angle view to see my scene from above.
Here is my starting code :
          <PerspectiveCamera
            makeDefault
            rotation={[0, 4.7, 0]}
            position={[-20, 7, 0]}
            fov={60}
            near={1}
            far={100}
          />
          <PerspectiveCamera
            ref={cameraRef}
            rotation={[0, 4.7, 0]}
            position={[-20, 7, 0]}
            fov={50}
            near={1}
            far={100}
          />


I'm changing the x axis rotation value but it seems that it effects y axis rotation...
      <PerspectiveCamera
        makeDefault
        rotation={[0, 4.7, 0]}
        position={[-20, 7, 0]}
        fov={60}
        near={1}
        far={100}
      />
      <PerspectiveCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        rotation={[1, 4.7, 0]}  // HERE IS WHAT I CHANGED !
        position={[-20, 7, 0]}
        fov={50}
        near={1}
        far={100}
      />

If I change x axis rotation here is the result... Weird ?

I would like to set my camera seeing from above to bottom, something like that :

If i just change the x-axis rotation then the result is what i'm looking for for that x rotation :
          <PerspectiveCamera
        makeDefault 
        rotation={[0, 4.7, 0]}
        position={[-20, 7, 0]} 
        fov={60} 
        near={1}
        far={100}
      />
      <PerspectiveCamera
        ref={cameraRef} 
        rotation={[-0.5, 0, 0]}
        position={[-20, 7, 0]} 
        fov={50} 
        near={1}
        far={100}
      />


Thanks for your help.
Here is the full code :
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import React, { Suspense, useRef } from 'react';
import SoccerField from '../models/SoccerField.jsx';
import SoccerBall from '../models/SoccerBall.jsx';
import {
CameraControls,
MeshReflectorMaterial,
PerspectiveCamera,
useHelper
} from '@react-three/drei';
import { degToRad } from 'maath/misc';
import Trophy from '../models/Trophy.jsx';
import SoccerStadium from '../models/SoccerStadium.jsx';
import { AxesHelper, CameraHelper } from 'three';

const SoccerScene = () => {
const controls = useRef();
const directionalLightRef = useRef();
console.log(directionalLightRef);

const cameraRef = useRef();
console.log(cameraRef);
return (
<section className="w-full h-screen relative bg-[#dfd6c6]">
  <Canvas
    className={`w-full h-screen bg-transparent`}
    shadows
  >
    {cameraRef.current && <primitive object={new 
CameraHelper(cameraRef.current)} />}

    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <primitive object={new AxesHelper(5)} />

      <directionalLight
        ref={directionalLightRef}
        position={[60, 100, 100]}
        rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
        intensity={2}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize-width={4096 * 2} // Augmente la résolution de l'ombre
        shadow-mapSize-height={4096 * 2} // Augmente la résolution de l'ombre
        shadow-camera-left={-50} // Augmente la largeur de la caméra d'ombre
        shadow-camera-right={50} // Augmente la largeur de la caméra d'ombre
        shadow-camera-top={10} // Augmente la hauteur de la caméra d'ombre
        shadow-camera-bottom={-10}
      />
      {/*{directionalLightRef.current && (*/}
      {/*  <cameraHelper args={[directionalLightRef.current.shadow.camera]} />*/}
      {/*)}*/}
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <pointLight
        position={[10, 5, 10]}
        intensity={2}
      />
      <spotLight
        position={[0, 50, 10]}
        angle={0.15}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={2}
      />
      <hemisphereLight
        skyColor="#b1e1ff"
        groundColor="#000000"
        intensity={1}
      />

      {/* Caméra principale avec ref */}
      <PerspectiveCamera
        makeDefault // Cela définira cette caméra comme la caméra par défaut
        rotation={[0, 4.7, 0]}
        position={[-20, 7, 0]} // Position de la caméra pour ajuster l'angle
        fov={60} // Vous pouvez ajuster le champ de vision pour changer l'angle
        near={1}
        far={100}
      />
      <PerspectiveCamera
        ref={cameraRef} // Attachement de la ref ici
        rotation={[0, 4.7, 0]}
        position={[-20, 7, 0]} // Position de la caméra pour ajuster l'angle
        fov={50} // Vous pouvez ajuster le champ de vision pour changer l'angle
        near={1}
        far={100}
      />
      {/* Utilisation du CameraHelper */}
      {cameraRef.current && <primitive object={new CameraHelper(cameraRef.current)} />}

      <CameraControls
        ref={controls}
        // minPolarAngle={degToRad(20)}
        // maxPolarAngle={degToRad(90)}
      />
      <SoccerStadium
        scale={0.1}
        position={[10, 0, 0]}
      />
      <group
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        position={[-5, 4.3, -3]}
      >
        <Trophy
          scale={3}
          position={[10, 0, 2]}
        />
        <SoccerBall
          position={[5, -1, 2]}
          scale={0.5}
        />
      </group>
    </Suspense>
  </Canvas>
</section>
);
};

export default SoccerScene;


I'm not familiar with react-three syntax. But I can try to help you with the direction of solving the problem. In order for the camera to look at the object from above, you need to set its height by 'position.y' above the object. And set the camera target (that is, where the camera looks) to the object. For this, the camera target vector must match the position of your object's vector.
